# Javascript .`keypress` event not firing on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, onkeypress

On this page:

https://subnetipv4.com/

If you click on any of the input boxes in the "IP Address" column, and press the "." or "/" keys (period or slash) it jumps you to the next input box.

Or at least, it does on a desktop browser. On a mobile browser, it doesn't seem to register the `onkeypress` event.

This is the code that is enabling the "jump" on period or slash presses:

```
        // Function to jump to next box on . or / keys
        function jumpdot(event) {
            // Capture pressed key:
            var y = event.key;

            if (y == "." || y == "/" ) {
                // . or / was pressed, jump to next userinput box and prevent typing of . or /
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementsByName(uiNext)[0].focus();
            }
        }
```

Is there an easy way to enable that functionality on Mobile phones as well?

*edit:  Updated website URL*

Answer (score 9):

The `keypress` event is marked as [Legacy in the DOM-Level-3 Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#legacy-keyboardevent-event-types).

> Warning. The keypress event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use of this event type.

Use the `keydown` event instead. Info: [Keydown Event in Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

You should also consider ...

> KeyboardEvent.which : Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use KeyboardEvent.key instead, if available.
>
> KeyboardEvent.keyCode : Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use KeyboardEvent.key instead, if available.

To read the pressed Key , use instead `event.key`

Comment: I changed the `onkeypress` to `onkeydown`, also had to change the period and slash keycode (from 46/47 to 190/191). Thanks!  But... when I changed `var x = event.which || event.keyCode;` to `var x = event.key;` it didn't work. Can you provide any more guidance?

Comment: PS: I'm testing on http://www.practicalnetworking.net/subnet2.html if you want to take a look.

Comment: Nevermind, event.key uses different key "codes". I updated the code and got that working.  Thank for the tips, @Colxi.

Comment: (sorry for 4 comments in a row) Unfortunately, this didn't help with the original issue -- the "jump to next box" on pressing period or slash still only works with desktop browsers and not mobile browsers =/.

Comment: wich is the value of  'document.getElementsByName(uiNext)[0]'  when you press the period or slash key ? Try to send ot to the console, to double check, the selector is not missbehaving

Comment: I changed it to event.key, which returns "." and "/" when period or slash is pressed. I've updated my code to look for "." or "/" to trigger the jumpdot function. HOWEVER, on Mobile, I can press period or slash all I want and nothing happens.

Comment: I switched from `event.code` to `event.key` and it works for android.

Answer (score 0):

ev.keyCode can be helpful. That provides more info about a keystroke.

Comment: But apparently it is deprecated, according to @colxi 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49993951/1110324) . I've changed the code to event.key and that part is working. The mobile functionality is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `oninput:` instead of `onkeypress:`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30126865)