# is there a mobile friendly way to detect enter key presses in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I want to detect when the enter key is pressed in a textarea

**I want it to work on *mobile* too**

When the textarea is focused, and they press enter on the onscreen keyboard, it still detects and when they are using an external keyboard or computer keyboard it also detects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly check the `keyCode`.

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) alert('Enter');
});
```

Comment: Does `keypress` really work for mobile? It seems like a lot of posts say to not use `keypress`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992576/javascript-keypress-event-not-firing-on-mobile-device When I try on mobile, I always get 229 for they keyCode.